# Does npm use the npm defined in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

Does `npm` use the `npm` defined in `package.json`?

```
$ npm --version
4.5.0
```

package.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "npm": "4.3.0"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Yes and no

When you run `npm install` you will not use that version of npm for that, but whatever version you have first in `PATH` will be used and it will install that specified version of npm in your `node_modules` directory.

Now, since npm adds `node_modules/.bin` to your PATH when it runs the npm scripts like `npm test` or `npm start` or `npm run whatever` etc., it **will** use the specific version of npm if you happen to use npm inside of your scripts.

For example if you have:

```
"start": "npm run execute",
"execute": "node app.js",
```

in `package.json`, then when you run:

```
npm start
```

your usual npm will be used for that, but it will run the specific installed npm for `npm run execute` which in turn will run `node app.js`.

### Example

If you have this package.json:

```
{
  "name": "npm-install-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "npm-v": "npm -v"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

And **before you run `npm install`** you run:

```
$ npm -v
```

you get:

```
4.2.0
```

and when you run:

```
$ npm run npm-v
```

you get:

```
> npm-install-test@1.0.0 npm-v /home/rsp/node/test/npm-install-test
> npm -v

4.2.0
```

Now, **after you run `npm install`** when you run:

```
$ npm -v
```

you still get:

```
4.2.0
```

but when you run:

```
$ npm run npm-v
```

you now get:

```
> npm-install-test@1.0.0 npm-v /home/rsp/node/test/npm-install-test
> npm -v

4.3.0
```

Of course your version may vary. I just happened to have npm 4.2.0 installed while doing those tests. If you have 4.3.0 installed then you will not see the effect of course.

Comment: If I want to make sure that the version of `npm` in `package.json` is used during install, I must do: `npm run foo-task` where `foo-task` calls `npm install`?